# Running a query in loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am in the process of moving my PhP driven site to the Codeingniter framework. All is going well and I am really happy with how organized the MVC is making my code. 
I have run into a little issue that I am not sure how to solve.
Hope I can explain it. Here goes,

I have a query in a model that pulls event info. After passing the data from the controller to the view I run a foreach loop.

With the old code during the while loop from the first query i run another query during the loop that gets the rank from the same table for each race in the loop using the $r_id=$rowsraces['race_id'] field from the first loop.

I need to pull the rank of the member as i loop threw the first query of the different races. Any Ideas?

```
$races=mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM spe_picks
    JOIN races
    ON races.race_id=spe_picks.race_id
    WHERE round_total>0
    AND YEAR(race_time)=2015
    GROUP BY races.race_id
    "); 
while ($rowsraces = mysql_fetch_array($races)){
           $r_id=$rowsraces['race_id'];
   echo "<a href='../results/?r_id=".$r_id."' style='text-decoration:none'>";
   echo $rowsraces['race_name'];
   echo "</a>";
$query_rank=mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT *, @rank := @rank +1 rank 
    FROM (SELECT user_id,round_total, round_drop, MAX(pick_date) Max_date
    FROM spe_picks 
    WHERE race_id=$r_id
    GROUP BY user_id)s, (SELECT @rank :=0)init 
    ORDER BY round_total DESC, Max_date ASC)r WHERE user_id =$user ");
while ($rows9 = mysql_fetch_array($query_rank)){

   echo "<span class='badge'>".ordinal_suffix($rows9['rank'], 'sup')."
    }   
}
```

What I need to know is how should I execute this with Codeigniter's MVC approach?

Thanks

Comment: All the database related work should be done in the model and not the view. You can use objects or arrays to pass the data from the model to the controller to the view. For some repeated HTML patterns, I use template generating libraries which I created, or view templates can also be used, as we can use more then one view file in the final HTML that we send to the Browser. The CodeIgniter makes database transactions very easy by using Active Records and Database Helpers. Here have a look : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/#database-reference

Comment: I understand all of my database ops are in models. The question is more about how to execute this and not how to use Codeigniter.

Comment: This is my old code. I need a way of migrating this into the Codeigniter framework